# Does PostgreSQL benefit from more cores or faster cores for READ heavy applications?

Tags: postgresql, performance, union, blob

I have been trying to figure out how to go about configuration of a PostgreSQL instance that will have 64GB ram (which is far larger than the database) and if I should opt for more cores or faster cores.(Assuming passmark total is within 15-20% difference)

Some extra details:
The most intensive READ will be JSONB through lots of UNION. The OS in this case is CentOS 6.

Answer (score 10):

## Memory related settings

You've already addressed the key bottleneck for read heavy applications, that is, having sufficient RAM for caching.  Just make sure you've set appropriately high values for `shared_bufferes`, `work_mem`, `maintenance_work_mem`, and `effective_cache_size` within your `postgresql.conf` file.

Actually, there's a litany of good info in [this DBA.SE thread.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance)

Also, here's a link to the [Postgres Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-resource.html) about these settings, amongst others.

## Processor choice

As for choice of processors, it is important to keep in mind that Postgres is not capable of using more than one CPU per database process.  If there will be many concurrently connected users, a multi-core CPU can spread out the user queries amongst the cores, but cannot parallelize on a per-query basis. Effectively, you will only get to truly leverage a benefit from multiple cores when there are multiple connected users.

I guess, to answer succinctly, that if you have only one (or a small number) of users, favor faster cores, whereas if you'll have many concurrent users, you could benefit from a little of both.

Refer to [this DBA.SE thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55019/can-a-single-postgresql-query-use-multiple-cores) which covers some of this info.

If you are going to have many concurrently users, I would suggest you also look in to [connection pooling](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections).

Comment: Agreed. Depends almost totally on the workload. Big complex queries: fewer faster cores. Lots of concurrent simple queries: more faster cores. If in doubt, go for fewer faster cores, since you can queue up high-query-rate workloads via something like PgBouncer, but you can't (unfortunately) make one query use more than one core in PostgreSQL.

(Yes, I know about PL/Proxy, but you've got to be desperate to go that way).

Comment: 9.6 and later can use multiple cpus for one query. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/parallel-query.html